# My DIVS will not sit correctly

Tags: html, css

I have been stuck on this for weeks now!! I am trying to get my sign up form to sit on the right next to all the text and banner however nomatter what i do this will not work.

Below is all the HTML and CSS i am currently using.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <style>
    body
    {
        background: url(http://www.catalink.com/images/christmas-1211.jpg);
    }
    .outer
    {
        margin: auto;
        width: 910px;
    }
    .inner
    {
        background: white;
        width: 905px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    .image
    {
        float: left;
    }
    .catname
    {
        margin-right: 180px;
        margin-left: 245px;
        background: #cae1ff;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 18px;
        height: 20px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        border-color: #828282;
    }
    .catcopy
    {
        margin-right: 180px;
        padding-left: 28%;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    .banner
    {
        margin-left: 250px;
        margin-right: 180px;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    .singlelineform
    {
        background: #DDD;
        width: 150px;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        border-radius: 12px;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    .ntitle
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    .fname
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
        padding: 2px;
    }
    .day
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    .month
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    .year
    {
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 18px;
    }
    button, input, select, textarea {
      font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
      input
    {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
    }
    select
    {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
    }
    button
    {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
      -moz-border-radius: 12px;
      -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
      border-radius: 12px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    <div class="image"><img src="http://www.catalink.com/images/cat/extralarge/burton-1208d.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="catname"><b>Burton eNewsletter</b></div>
    <div class="catcopy"><p><b>Outfitters of the Modern British Man...</b></p><p><b>Burton believes in combining accessible style with great value.</b> They want fashion to be easy and comfortable as well as stylish. They embrace their British tailoring roots but they also understand the importance of kicking back in a great pair of jeans and a hoodie. They love a good laugh, but they also know the importance of <b>"looking the business"</b></p></div>
    <div class="banner"><a href="http://www.burton.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TopCategoriesDisplay?storeId=12551&catalogId=33052" target="blank"><img src="http://www.catalink.com/images/450ban/burton-450ban-1208b.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>
    <div class="singlelineform">
    <form>
    <div class="formtitle"><b>To request this brochure please fill out the form below.</b></div>
    <div class="ntitle"><b>First Name*:</b><br><select>
      <option value="title">Title</option>
      <option value="mr">Mr</option>
      <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
      <option value="miss">Miss</option>
      <option value="ms">Ms</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="fname">
    <input type="firstname" name="fname" /></div>
    <div class="lname"><b>Last Name:*</b><input type="lastname" name="lname" /></div>
    <div class="day"><b>Date of Birth*:</b>
    <select name="date" form="dateform">
    <option value="day">Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="21">21</option>
    <option value="22">22</option>
    <option value="23">23</option>
    <option value="24">24</option>
    <option value="25">25</option>
    <option value="26">26</option>
    <option value="27">27</option>
    <option value="28">28</option>
    <option value="29">29</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="month">
    <select form="monthhform">
    <option value="month">Month</option>
    <option value="january">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="year">
    <select form="yearform">
    <option value="year">Year</option>
    <option value="1994">1994</option>
    <option value="1993">1993</option>
    <option value="1992">1992</option>
    <option value="1991">1991</option>
    <option value="1990">1990</option>
    <option value="1989">1989</option>
    <option value="1988">1988</option>
    <option value="1987">1987</option>
    <option value="1986">1986</option>
    <option value="1985">1985</option>
    <option value="1984">1984</option>
    <option value="1983">1983</option>
    <option value="1982">1982</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1979">1979</option>
    <option value="1978">1978</option>
    <option value="1977">1977</option>
    <option value="1976">1976</option>
    <option value="1975">1975</option>
    <option value="1974">1974</option>
    <option value="1973">1973</option>
    <option value="1972">1972</option>
    <option value="1971">1971</option>
    <option value="1970">1970</option>
    <option value="1969">1969</option>
    <option value="1968">1968</option>
    <option value="1967">1967</option>
    <option value="1966">1966</option>
    <option value="1965">1965</option>
    <option value="1964">1964</option>
    <option value="1963">1963</option>
    <option value="1962">1962</option>
    <option value="1961">1961</option>
    <option value="1960">1960</option>
    <option value="1959">1959</option>
    <option value="1958">1958</option>
    <option value="1957">1957</option>
    <option value="1956">1956</option>
    <option value="1955">1955</option>
    <option value="1954">1954</option>
    <option value="1953">1953</option>
    <option value="1952">1952</option>
    <option value="1951">1951</option>
    <option value="1950">1950</option>
    <option value="1949">1949</option>
    <option value="1948">1948</option>
    <option value="1947">1947</option>
    <option value="1946">1946</option>
    <option value="1945">1945</option>
    <option value="1944">1944</option>
    <option value="1943">1943</option>
    <option value="1942">1942</option>
    <option value="1941">1941</option>
    <option value="1940">1940</option>
    <option value="1939">1939</option>
    <option value="1938">1938</option>
    <option value="1937">1937</option>
    <option value="1936">1936</option>
    <option value="1935">1935</option>
    <option value="1934">1934</option>
    <option value="1933">1933</option>
    <option value="1932">1932</option>
    <option value="1931">1931</option>
    <option value="1930">1930</option>
    <option value="1929">1929</option>
    <option value="1928">1928</option>
    <option value="1927">1927</option>
    <option value="1926">1926</option>
    <option value="1925">1925</option>
    <option value="1924">1924</option>
    <option value="1923">1923</option>
    <option value="1922">1922</option>
    <option value="1921">1921</option>
    <option value="1920">1920</option>
    <option value="1919">1919</option>
    <option value="1918">1918</option>
    <option value="1917">1917</option>
    <option value="1916">1916</option>
    <option value="1915">1915</option>
    <option value="1914">1914</option>
    <option value="1913">1913</option>
    <option value="1912">1912</option>
    <option value="1911">1911</option>
    <option value="1910">1910</option>
    </select></div>
    <div class="email"><b>Email:*</b><input type="email" name="email" /></div>
    <div class="hnumber"><b>House Number*:</b><input type="houseno" name="address" /></div>
    <div class="pcode"><b>Post Code:*</b><input type="pcode" name="email" />
    <button type="submit" name="faddress">Find Address</button></div>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please replace your code example with just the relevant code and possibly create a JSFiddle example that shows your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outer{
margin: auto;
width: 910px;
position: relative;
}

.singlelineform {
background: #DDD;
width: 150px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 18px;
border: solid;
border-width: thin;
border-radius: 12px;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2BgV/1/

Comment: Thank you for this. Please could you explain where I went wrong and also could you please explain how I could make the white background the same height as the form?

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            background: url(http://www.catalink.com/images/christmas-1211.jpg);
        }
        .outer
        {
            margin: auto;
            width: 910px;
        }
        .inner
        {
            background: white;
            width: 905px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        .image
        {
            float: left;
        }
        .catname
        {
            margin-right: 180px;
            margin-left: 245px;
            background: #cae1ff;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 18px;
            height: 20px;
            border: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            border-color: #828282;
        }
        .catcopy
        {
            margin-right: 180px;
            padding-left: 28%;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 11px;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
        .banner
        {
            margin-left: 250px;
            margin-right: 180px;
            padding-top: 25px;
        }
        .singlelineform
        {
            background: #DDD;
            width: 150px;
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            border: solid;
            border-width: thin;
            border-radius: 12px;
            padding: 5px;
            float: right;
        }
        .ntitle
        {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
        .fname
        {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
            padding: 2px;
        }
        .day
        {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
        .month
        {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
        .year
        {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 18px;
        }
        button, input, select, textarea
        {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
        }
        input
        {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }
        select
        {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }
        button
        {
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -khtml-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
            -moz-border-radius: 12px;
            -khtml-border-radius: 12px;
            border-radius: 12px;
        }
        .clear
        {
            width: 100%;
            height: 0px;
            clear: both;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="singlelineform">
                <form>
                <div class="formtitle">
                    <b>To request this brochure please fill out the form below.</b></div>
                <div class="ntitle">
                    <b>First Name*:</b><br>
                    <select>
                        <option value="title">Title</option>
                        <option value="mr">Mr</option>
                        <option value="mrs">Mrs</option>
                        <option value="miss">Miss</option>
                        <option value="ms">Ms</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="fname">
                    <input type="firstname" name="fname" /></div>
                <div class="lname">
                    <b>Last Name:*</b><input type="lastname" name="lname" /></div>
                <div class="day">
                    <b>Date of Birth*:</b>
                    <select name="date" form="dateform">
                        <option value="day">Day</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                        <option value="8">8</option>
                        <option value="9">9</option>
                        <option value="10">10</option>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                        <option value="13">13</option>
                        <option value="14">14</option>
                        <option value="15">15</option>
                        <option value="16">16</option>
                        <option value="17">17</option>
                        <option value="18">18</option>
                        <option value="19">19</option>
                        <option value="20">20</option>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                        <option value="23">23</option>
                        <option value="24">24</option>
                        <option value="25">25</option>
                        <option value="26">26</option>
                        <option value="27">27</option>
                        <option value="28">28</option>
                        <option value="29">29</option>
                        <option value="30">30</option>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="month">
                    <select form="monthhform">
                        <option value="month">Month</option>
                        <option value="january">January</option>
                        <option value="february">February</option>
                        <option value="march">March</option>
                        <option value="april">April</option>
                        <option value="may">May</option>
                        <option value="june">June</option>
                        <option value="july">July</option>
                        <option value="august">August</option>
                        <option value="september">September</option>
                        <option value="october">October</option>
                        <option value="november">November</option>
                        <option value="december">December</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="year">
                    <select form="yearform">
                        <option value="year">Year</option>
                        <option value="1994">1994</option>
                        <option value="1993">1993</option>
                        <option value="1992">1992</option>
                        <option value="1991">1991</option>
                        <option value="1990">1990</option>
                        <option value="1989">1989</option>
                        <option value="1988">1988</option>
                        <option value="1987">1987</option>
                        <option value="1986">1986</option>
                        <option value="1985">1985</option>
                        <option value="1984">1984</option>
                        <option value="1983">1983</option>
                        <option value="1982">1982</option>
                        <option value="1981">1981</option>
                        <option value="1980">1980</option>
                        <option value="1979">1979</option>
                        <option value="1978">1978</option>
                        <option value="1977">1977</option>
                        <option value="1976">1976</option>
                        <option value="1975">1975</option>
                        <option value="1974">1974</option>
                        <option value="1973">1973</option>
                        <option value="1972">1972</option>
                        <option value="1971">1971</option>
                        <option value="1970">1970</option>
                        <option value="1969">1969</option>
                        <option value="1968">1968</option>
                        <option value="1967">1967</option>
                        <option value="1966">1966</option>
                        <option value="1965">1965</option>
                        <option value="1964">1964</option>
                        <option value="1963">1963</option>
                        <option value="1962">1962</option>
                        <option value="1961">1961</option>
                        <option value="1960">1960</option>
                        <option value="1959">1959</option>
                        <option value="1958">1958</option>
                        <option value="1957">1957</option>
                        <option value="1956">1956</option>
                        <option value="1955">1955</option>
                        <option value="1954">1954</option>
                        <option value="1953">1953</option>
                        <option value="1952">1952</option>
                        <option value="1951">1951</option>
                        <option value="1950">1950</option>
                        <option value="1949">1949</option>
                        <option value="1948">1948</option>
                        <option value="1947">1947</option>
                        <option value="1946">1946</option>
                        <option value="1945">1945</option>
                        <option value="1944">1944</option>
                        <option value="1943">1943</option>
                        <option value="1942">1942</option>
                        <option value="1941">1941</option>
                        <option value="1940">1940</option>
                        <option value="1939">1939</option>
                        <option value="1938">1938</option>
                        <option value="1937">1937</option>
                        <option value="1936">1936</option>
                        <option value="1935">1935</option>
                        <option value="1934">1934</option>
                        <option value="1933">1933</option>
                        <option value="1932">1932</option>
                        <option value="1931">1931</option>
                        <option value="1930">1930</option>
                        <option value="1929">1929</option>
                        <option value="1928">1928</option>
                        <option value="1927">1927</option>
                        <option value="1926">1926</option>
                        <option value="1925">1925</option>
                        <option value="1924">1924</option>
                        <option value="1923">1923</option>
                        <option value="1922">1922</option>
                        <option value="1921">1921</option>
                        <option value="1920">1920</option>
                        <option value="1919">1919</option>
                        <option value="1918">1918</option>
                        <option value="1917">1917</option>
                        <option value="1916">1916</option>
                        <option value="1915">1915</option>
                        <option value="1914">1914</option>
                        <option value="1913">1913</option>
                        <option value="1912">1912</option>
                        <option value="1911">1911</option>
                        <option value="1910">1910</option>
                    </select></div>
                <div class="email">
                    <b>Email:*</b><input type="email" name="email" /></div>
                <div class="hnumber">
                    <b>House Number*:</b><input type="houseno" name="address" /></div>
                <div class="pcode">
                    <b>Post Code:*</b><input type="pcode" name="email" />
                    <button type="submit" name="faddress">
                        Find Address</button></div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="image">
                <img src="http://www.catalink.com/images/cat/extralarge/burton-1208d.jpg" /></div>
            <div class="catname">
                <b>Burton eNewsletter</b></div>
            <div class="catcopy">
                <p>
                    <b>Outfitters of the Modern British Man...</b></p>
                <p>
                    <b>Burton believes in combining accessible style with great value.</b> They want
                    fashion to be easy and comfortable as well as stylish. They embrace their British
                    tailoring roots but they also understand the importance of kicking back in a great
                    pair of jeans and a hoodie. They love a good laugh, but they also know the importance
                    of <b>"looking the business"</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="banner">
                <a href="http://www.burton.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/TopCategoriesDisplay?storeId=12551&catalogId=33052"
                    target="blank">
                    <img src="http://www.catalink.com/images/450ban/burton-450ban-1208b.jpg" border="0" /></a></div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you want to achieve?

http://jsfiddle.net/c4GPW/
    ​

Comment: Yes but it all needs to be inside the outer div

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - all the markup is surrounded by `<div class="outer">`